# Do you need to fight Miracle Matter twice?

Tags: kirby-64-the-crystal-shards

In Kirby 64: The Crystal Shards, you need to collect all of the crystal shards and fight Miracle Matter in order to get the good ending. However, for some reason I was under the impression that even if you did get all the shards (except the one that Miracle Matter itself drops) and defeat Miracle Matter, you get the bad ending and must fight miracle matter again in order to unlock Dark Star. But after a quick google search, I couldn't figure out whether or not this was right.

Do you need to fight Miracle Matter twice in order to get the good ending?